# How to simulate an Error in React functional component with Jest?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, integration-testing, react-testing-library

I would like to test if my *App* component handles any error and render the correct component (UnhandledError).

Here is an example for *App* component

```
export function App() {
return (
        <ErrorBoundary fallback={<UnhandledError />}>
            <Suspense fallback={<Loader />}>
                <div>Component tree that triggers Suspense...</div>
            </Suspense>
        </ErrorBoundary>
);}
```

I am a bit unsure how to setup test for this, I am assuming that the best approach would be to render *App* and mock *Loader* so that it  throws an Error instead of rendering...
I have been trying to mock my *Loader* without any luck making it work.

If this is the case, and assuming that the *Loader* is also a Functional Component, is there a way to mock it, and for a single test only, so that it throws an Error only for a specific test in test file ?

I am using Create React App (v5) with jest@27.4.7 and typescript@4.5.4.
Any help would be very, very appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is similar to what you want? https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2022/01/building-real-app-react-query/

Answer (score 0):

you can use the function simulateError() for simulate the error.. look this documentation

```
function MockChildren() {
  // this is just a placeholder
  return null;
}

it('renders an error page if there is a crash error', () => {
const root = mount(
    <ErrorPageGuard>
      <MockChildren />
    </ErrorPageGuard>
);

const error = new Error('TEST ERROR');
root.find(MockChildren).simulateError(error);

expect(root.state('hasError')).toBe(true);



});
```

https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/simulateError.html

it works for me.